# Implementing Interface and initialise it in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, class, interface, asp.net-mvc-5, dataabstract

I am working with the web application and I have a class which have all the business logic which implement Interface. I am trying to referenced Interface and class in startup.cs and trying to initialise in Controller. My business logic class is like this:

```
 public class User_MasterDataAccesss: IUserMasterRepository
 {
   .... business logic
   public int validate(string name)
   {
     ...... doing something
   }
 }
```

I have an interface which have definition for the validate function like this

```
public interface IUserMasterRepository
{
    int validate(string name);
}
```

I am trying to bind the interface in startup.cs like this

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.           
       // services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddSingleton<IUserMasterRepository, User_MasterDataAccesss>();

    }
}
```

and I am trying to initialise the interface in controller like this

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    private  IUserMasterRepository UserMasterRepository;
    public AuthenticationController() { }
    public AuthenticationController(IUserMasterRepository userMasterRepository)
    {
        this.UserMasterRepository = userMasterRepository;
    }
    ......... action result actions which is using the UserMasterRepository 

 }
```

My problem is as follows:

1. Constructor is not executing and as a result `UserMasterRepository` is null when accessing from action.
2. `services.AddMvc();` in startup.cs is doesnot exist
3. I know I can achieve my requirement by using Ninject but I want to use startup.cs file for that matter
4. I do not want to use new key word in controller.

How can I achieve this? Where I am wrong?

Comment: If `services.AddMvc()` is not available it sounds like you have a reference issue.  Make sure you have installed the Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-rc1-final`.  And make sure you have the correct `using` statements.

Comment: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3' already exists in project and trying to add the package gives error      Install-Package : Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime 4.0.0-rc1-final constraint: 
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (≥ 4.0.0-rc1-final)',

Comment: What about your `using` statements?  Nothing will work until you can get `services.AddMvc()` working in the `ConfigureServices()` method and `app.UseMvc()` in the `Configure()` method.  I have a simple project that works with these `using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing  [ASP.NET 5 runtime and tooling](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html) solve my problem.